May I convince X that my DPI is 185?
$ xrandr --prop | grep mm
eDP-1 connected primary 2160x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 296mm x 197mm
$ xdpyinfo | grep millimeters
  dimensions:    2160x1440 pixels (572x381 millimeters)
$ echo '2k2160 296 25.4//p' | dc
185.40
$ echo '2k2160 572 25.4//p' | dc
95.95
$ 

With respect to the monitor size in mm, the first output is correct and we can derive a DPI value of 185, the second is wrong but it's consistent with the unnecessary(?) default value of 96 DPI.
This can be regarded as a curiosity but it has an important consequence, all X clients think that a 10pt font (e.g., xterm -fa mono-10) should be 13px high, while to be visually 10pt high on the physical display it should be 26px high — in other words the xterm of the above example has a 5pt font, almost inintelligible.
How can I convince the X server that the real DPI to be used by the clients is 185?

Related article on Arch wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/HiDPI in particular, the Xft.dpi X resource is important for applications using Xlib, as well as setting the X.Org configuration files and/or calling xrandr --dpi with a particular DPI value as argument.

@Vilinkameni Some programs are aware  of the Xft.dpi X resource, most are not... xrandr knows from minte zero that the display is 185 dpi. Now I will read the link you suggested, thank you
